# How to use flume creating a task to load data from HDFS to HIVE automatic by time?

Tags: hadoop, hive, flume

I need to load data from hadoop to hive automatic, but I don't wanna setup an other service to do this thing. I already use flume to collect my logs...... So how should I do?
Does flume can exec a command (a query for hive just like LOAD.....)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather have Flume to store the extracted data under Hive's table directory (typically /user/hive/warehouse/Your_Table_Dierctory). Nothing more needs to be done.

Comment: But in this case, we still need to execute the command 'load' right?
Because the data just save in the hdfs not in the hive tables.

Comment: Not required. Hive refers to the HDFS files eventually. The load is not a real parse and load. For managed tables the files are stored under the path /user/hive/warehouse directory (sub directories are created for each table under this path). If it an external table, it can refer to the path outside the above HDFS path as well. All that you need to do is to bring the file into the respective Hive table's HDFS directory. It is as good as the LOAD

Comment: Great! This is a good but sometimes I will got file not found, because the FlumeData.log.temp is changed to FlumeData.log......
How to solve this problem in this answer?

Comment: Not sure how this is connected with the loading issue. Are you loading the Flume log file into Hive? Please elaborate little bit

Comment: Ok, maybe I need create the other question that is taliking about how to fix the file not found while Flume change the data name from "data.temp(the surfix)" to "data" in /user/hive/warehouse/myTable ,the hive execute the map/reduce will fail because not found data.temp in /user/hive/warehouse/myTable

Comment: Just to add, if you have partitioned the Hive table and Flume has created a new partition e.g. date=2014-07-02, then you will need to tell Hive about that partition using the command ALTER TABLE xxx ADD PARTITION(date='2014-07-02').

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I am a little late to the party here, but I have actually put together a very complete example of how to do this with all the details exposed.  Perhaps, it will help someone else

http://www.lopakalogic.com/articles/hadoop-articles/log-files-flume-hive/

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.